# VLAN Access Ports

Tags: vlan

I wanted to know whether all the ports on a switch are **access ports** by default and do they belong to vlan 1? Can another vlan be made a default vlan?

Comment: That depends on your switch model. An unmanaged switch will only have a single, native VLAN. You cannot give it a VLAN number since it doesn't know about VLANs. For managed switches, the default VLAN is usually VLAN 1, and it is the native VLAN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In production environment things are a little more complicated, there are a lot of devices and operating systems there.

But if we talk about the Cisco Packet Tracer – which is one of the most recommended network simulation program in case you study for CCNA – you have not many choices. Open a switch – 2950 or 2960 model – and use the command:

```
Switch> show interfaces switchport
```

You will see that all those 24 FastEthernet ports are by default **“Administrative Mode: dynamic auto”**, which literally means “passively waits to receive trunk negotiation messages, at which point the
 switch will respond and negotiate whether to use trunking”. ( If they were “access ports” you should see **“Administrative Mode: static access”**.) If you want to find more about dynamic trunking search for the DTP (Dynamic Trunking Protocol), which is a proprietary networking protocol developed by Cisco for the purpose of negotiating trunking on a link between two VLAN-aware switches, and for negotiating the type of trunking encapsulation to be used.

And yes, VLAN 1 is the default native VLAN and - for security reasons - Cisco recommends to change it. There a bunch of ways to do that, check for “Implementing Ethernet Virtual LANs”. But I think it's essential to fully understand the concept firstly, otherwise everything becomes confusing...

Answer (score 2):

The reasony why VLAN 1 is the default VLAN is not a vendor-specific implementation, but a decision made by IEEE. On page 222, 802.1Q-2014 says about **VLAN** identifier **1**: *The default PVID value used for classifying frames on ingress through a Bridge Port. The PVID value of a Port can be changed by management.* In more common terms: It's the default VLAN. If a vendor decides not to comply with IEEE's decision, then it's possible that such a feature is available.

**Native VLAN**: If an incoming frame is untagged, then it is associated with VLAN 1, unless configured otherwise. Consequently every untagged frame would be forwarded anywhere. To mitigate this security risk you should configure a **shutdown VLAN** on every switch. That's a VLAN which catches all untagged frames and prevents them from being forwarded because it only exists on that switch and none of its neighbors.

Side note: You can get the 802.1Q-2014 document for free via the [IEEE Get Program](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.1.html).